# OpenNMS HttpMonitor User Agent

Tags: c#-4.0

We use `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]` to fetch user agent and 
Request.Browser.Browser + " " + Request.Browser.Version to fetch browser details.

But some times logged User Agent is **OpenNMS HttpMonitor** and browser name is **UnKnown 0.0**.

Can anyone suggest what can be case for this?

Comment: OpenNMS is a network monitor tool (http://www.opennms.org). It provides page monitoring (HttpMonitor). This means some OpenNMS instance is monitoring your web site by periodically accessing your page and see if it is still up.

Answer (score 0):

When the HTTP request command is built up, only the User Agent is set in the HTTP header. An enhancement request or pull request would be required. The part of the code which is responsible for this behavior can be found here: https://github.com/OpenNMS/opennms/blob/develop/opennms-services/src/main/java/org/opennms/netmgt/poller/monitors/HttpMonitor.java#L562